# incomplete results on dig trace

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip, dig

According to an example here:
https://www.rootusers.com/12-dig-command-examples-to-query-dns-in-linux/

Such a dig trace `dig google.com +trace` should return such results:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> google.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.                       5       IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       5       IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
;; Received 493 bytes from 192.168.220.2#53(192.168.220.2) in 671 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.                    86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20160915170000 20160905160000 46551 . aRW+mmwKW6sWvAef35LCj5ZeQkFrOP8uWwMjQkPIqMfayBRuK1YuqF0h Pu0v4ZBaXPxj0KjmwLIry+Y8p6gIX7lFATfQmUNJcmFxaPYDdEuLYW4S 4idKDZkkEWA3LLUn9OQ0EdioR1PdVr/4xY/u48066DFDx5Vg6aEs1/0Q oXY=
;; Received 734 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 215 ms

google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20160911044243 20160904033243 27452 com. F8heeEXQl6/iOiPAJxfH/dIE7k6NkI0KDRH+evPdZJV6dUs4bYIfbvwI dIEmEDB1wn28MntLpjEixu+64VusOHrUaOXzg5I26D+UbUmksImr2a/P 39zxhHLIRJgYEUxrE1HrID+xY+PewGq3/aEVvPKofbO7/FyBJlmftQn6 12o=
S84AE3BIT99DKIHQH27TRC0584HV5KOH.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - S84J17P3PT4RKMEJOHNGD73C5Q5NV5S9 NS DS RRSIG
S84AE3BIT99DKIHQH27TRC0584HV5KOH.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20160909045208 20160902034208 27452 com. vxkCSPNnOpLiQNpsk1ZpsQzGMzNdbSpL6Up0Z0njXJrRUdD5eHC/tgnA cHc5mDX2IuuBqU65hZd40U2pSYCBeb5BfaRd9gaQIMyLBbBzd9nj2E+F 8LnTRqa+oXeYQVO1AlfysumdS/CgxwN0CidhCPxPQpPtfdnl6UaKxCzL 5d4=
;; Received 660 bytes from 192.31.80.30#53(d.gtld-servers.net) in 201 ms
```

However, when I try it, I get only this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> google.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 51 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) in 0 ms
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Without the `@` option, `dig` queries your systemd stub resolver, not an actual DNS server. For some reason the resolver refuses queries about NS record for '.' top domain, and `dig` cannot even start tracing.

```
16:31:45.992047 IP 127.0.0.1.56091 > 127.0.0.53.53: 58708 [1au] NS? . (40)
16:31:45.992184 IP 127.0.0.53.53 > 127.0.0.1.56091: 58708 Refused 0/0/1 (51)
```

I did not find any information in the systemd-resolved manual explaining why this is happening, nor any hint how to change this behaviour. I didn't search too long, though.

You can bypass the systemd resolver running `dig` with an excplicit DNS server address:

```
# dig @A.B.C.D +trace google.com
```

Replace `A.B.C.D` with your local DNS address.

Comment: I still don't get the required output even after adding my local DNS address.

Comment: Then debug it with tcpdump. You will see what is happening. It should work unless the external DNS also refuses root NS queries from clients.

Answer (score 0):

**dig +trace** runs iterative queries directly from your machine. You are likely running into firewall issues connecting to GTLD nameservers. OR you don't have a copy of the root hints.

**Normal DNS Traversel**
Your PC > ISP Resolver > Authoritative Nameservers

**DIG +Trace DNS Traversel**
Your PC > Authoritative Nameservers for root/com/google

If you want you can break it down into smaller chunks to troubleshoot.

Try this command

```
dig @198.41.0.4 google.com +norecurse
```

The IP address is for (a.root-servers.net) It should return you the NS records for 'com'

After that try

```
dig @192.5.6.30 google.com +norecurse
```

The IP address is for (a.gtld-servers.net) It should return you the NS records for 'google.com'

You get the idea. This is what dig +trace is doing. If you have a firewall issue, the above two commands will time out or fail for you too.

If they work for you, then the next possibility is that you don't have the root hints.

Try just typing 'dig' and hit enter. If you have root hints, the command will return you a list of the root servers. Is this same Ubuntu machine acting as your resolver? What do you see under /etc/resolv.conf